# Stokes Theorem without a boundary

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

Suppose I have a surface $S$ with no boundary e.g. a sphere. Can I still use Stokes' theorem? E.g. $$\int_S \nabla \times F\cdot dS= \int _{\partial \Sigma} F\cdot dr=0 \quad (\text{presumably?})$$

I guess this is instead saying "$\partial \Sigma=\emptyset$" not "$\partial\Sigma$ does not exist".

Comment: Here, $\partial S=\emptyset$ (not $\partial \Sigma$), hence the last integral is indeed $0$.

Comment: Cut your sphere in two, and perform the integration separately. Then the curve separating the hemispheres should give you opposite integrals. The sum is 0.